# Error when using basicAuth in PodMonitor in Managing GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Then I want to create PodMonitor using kubectl apply -f my-pod-monitor.yaml but I get error:

```
error: error validating "my-pod-monitor.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(PodMonitor.spec.podMetricsEndpoints[0]): unknown field "basicAuth" in io.gke.monitoring.v1alpha1.PodMonitor.spec.podMetricsEndpoints; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

my-pod-monitor.yaml

````
apiVersion: monitoring.gke.io/v1alpha1
kind: PodMonitor
metadata:
  name: my-pod-monitor-with-service-example
  namespace: test
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: prom-with_service-example
  podMetricsEndpoints:
    - port: metrics-port
      path: /metrics
      scheme: http
      interval: 60s
      basicAuth: 
        password: 
          password: basic-auth
          key: password
        username:
          name: basic-auth
          key: user
         ```
````

Comment: basicauth is not supported by API version from where you take refrence of this YAML ? are you trying to pass the secret?

Answer (score 0):

From https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/managing-metrics#workload-metrics:

> Note that this PodMonitor is in the monitoring.gke.io domain,
> rather than the monitoring.coreos.com domain used with the
> Prometheus Operator.  The PodMonitor supports a subset of the
> fields in the Prometheus Operator's PodMonitor.

If you need basic auth for PodMonitor you may consider switching to standard [Prometheus Operator](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator).